# Проблемы с Notepad++

Tags: php, dreamweaver

пишу один и тот же код на php в Dreamweaver и Notepad++.
через Dreamweaver браузер отображает все нормально, а через Notepad++ - браузер показывает сам код, не обрабатывая. файлы находятся в одной папке, денвер установлен. с чем может быть связано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php ?>
```

Не?

---

Вероятно файл открывается по полному пути без интерпритатора, то есть вместо example.com/file.php открывается file://C://...../www/file.php . Открывайте через браузер непосредственно адрес, а не сам файл. т.е. запуск через notepad++ не будет работать, так как вы в качестве параметра передаёте не адрес, где данный код будет интерпритирован, а файл, который будет распознан как текстовый с MIME text/html

Comment: с этого начинается

Comment: Может тогда код?

Comment: файл сам работает, если запустить. но если в самом ноутпаде Запуск>Launch in Chrome, то ничего не происходит. голый код. может че не так нажимаю в ноуте, чтобы предварительно посмотреть?

Comment: Вероятно файл открывается по полному пути без интерпритатора, то есть вместо example.com/file.php открывается file://C://...../www/file.php . Открывайте через браузер непосредственно адрес, а не сам файл. т.е. запуск через notepad++ не будет работать, так как вы в качестве параметра передаёте не адрес, где данный код будет интерпритирован, а файл, который будет распознан как текстовый с MIME text/html

Comment: Хотите предпросмотра - используйте модненькую IDE - Aptana Studio 3. Можно код смотреть прямо рядом с броузером (в соседней панели)

Comment: видимо, так и есть. спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Файлы *.php лежат в каталоге (под Denwer) ...home/localhost/www/...? Или набирай в адресной строке броузера localhost/file.php

Comment: C:\WebServers\home\localhost\www\php\ так лежат

Comment: Notepad++ у меня тоже самое показал (Denwer + Joomla). Ну и Бог с ним :) Я думаю это не такая уж большая проблема.